# roslaunch not working

Tags: turtlebot, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

When trying to run

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[keyboard_teleop.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_teleop] nor is [turtlebot_teleop] a launch file name 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

the file exists though and the whole installation before worked fine! I don't know where to look. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213624/roslaunch-not-working/) by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you remembered to `source /path/to/the/relevant/setup.bash` file in your terminal? You have to do that for every new terminal again, unless you've configured your `.bashrc` to do it for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-13**:
I configured my file to do it for me. It is really strange. I changed into my directory where the teleop.launch is located and ran

roslaunch keyboard_teleop.launch
im getting following output:

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-13**:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_key]: turtlebot_teleop
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
No processes to monitor
shutti

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-14**:
From your other questions I think you built the turtlebot pkgs from source, right? Is the workspace where you did that also sourced? Your (possibly truncated) error shows only the default paths, not a source workspace. If the 'turtlebot workspace' is not on the path, `roslaunch` can't find the pkgs.

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-15**:
Thanks! roslaunch seems to work now for bringup and communications. But I get the same error now when trying `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` ...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-15**:
Please add more detailed information (*edit* your question) on how you installed ROS (using the debs, completely from source, or just the turtlebot bits from source), how you catkin workspaces are layed out, how many you have and how you use them. Without that we can only guess at what is going on.